# Func delegate with no return type

Tags: c#, .net, types, parameters, delegates

All of the `Func<T>` delegates return a value. What are the .NET delegates that can be used with methods that return `void`?

Answer (score 938, accepted):

All Func delegates return something; all the Action delegates return void.

`Func<TResult>` takes no arguments and returns TResult:

```
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>()
```

`Action<T>` takes one argument and does not return a value:

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T obj)
```

`Action` is the simplest, 'bare' delegate:

```
public delegate void Action()
```

There's also `Func<TArg1, TResult>` and `Action<TArg1, TArg2>` (and others up to 16 arguments). All of these (except for `Action<T>`) are new to .NET 3.5 (defined in System.Core).

Comment: FYI, the next version of the base class library will include Func and Action types that support more than four formal parameters. I don't recall exactly how big they get.

Comment: Actually, it looks like they go up to 16 in 4.0.

Comment: 1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, ... this clearly indicates that the compiler will need to be able to cope with [more arguments to a function than it currently does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658883/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-that-a-c-sharp-method-can-be-defined-as) at some point in the future!

Comment: Actually, Tustin2121 is right, they went up to 16 parameters (plus a return type in the case of `Func<,,, ... ,>`) in .NET 4.0, but the last eight types of each "series" are defined in `System.Core.dll`, not in `mscorlib.dll`, so that would be the reason why michielvoo didn't see them. However, no more Funcs or Actions were added in .NET versions 4.5 and 4.5.1. Will this sequence become [A170836](http://oeis.org/A170836) or [A170875](http://oeis.org/A170875)? Stay tuned.

Comment: I get providing a few overloads with several arguments for convenience, but a certain point, just wrap your args in an object...

Answer (score 115):

> ... takes no arguments and has a void return type?

I believe `Action` is a solution to this.

Answer (score 62):

> All of the Func delegates take at least one parameter

That's not true.  They all take at least one type argument, but that argument determines the return type.

So `Func<T>` accepts no parameters and returns a value.  Use `Action` or `Action<T>` when you don't want to return a value.

Answer (score 31):

Try `System.Func<T>` and `System.Action`

Comment: I don't think the 0 arg and whatnot exist in .Net 2.0, though.

Comment: It's weird: Func doesn't exist at all in .Net 2.0, though Predicate and Action do.

Comment: For .NET 2.0 use MethodInvoker delegate.

Comment: .NET 2 also had (or has) a delegate type `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` which was like the later `Func<T, TResult>`. It was used in the `List<>.ConvertAll` method which projected every element in a `List<>` onto another object, and placed all the "function values" in a new `List<>`. (Later, one would often use Linq `Select` for that.)

Answer (score 8):

A very easy way to invoke return and non return value subroutines. is using **Func** and **Action** respectively. *(see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Try this this example

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private Func<string,string> FunctionPTR = null;  
    private Func<string,string, string> FunctionPTR1 = null;  
    private Action<object> ProcedurePTR = null; 



    private string Display(string message)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(message);  
        return null;  
    }  

    private string Display(string message1,string message2)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(message1);  
        Console.WriteLine(message2);  
        return null;  
    }  

    public void ObjectProcess(object param)
    {
        if (param == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter is null or missing");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object is valid");
        }
    }


    public void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        FunctionPTR = Display;  
        FunctionPTR1= Display;  
        ProcedurePTR = ObjectProcess;
        FunctionPTR("Welcome to function pointer sample.");  
        FunctionPTR1("Welcome","This is function pointer sample");   
        ProcedurePTR(new object());
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally you will want to write a delegate for event handling, in which case you can take advantage of [`System.EvenHandler<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) which implicitly accepts an argument of type `object` in addition to the second parameter that should derive from [`EventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). EventHandlers will return `void`

I personally found this useful during testing for creating a one-off callback in a function body.

Answer (score 1):

> ... takes no arguments and has a void return type?

If you are writing for `System.Windows.Forms`, You can also use:

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker()
```